# Why can't vertex indices be sorted by Z_VIEW in blender python？

Tags: python, 3d-view, vertices, edges, bmesh

Run the following code:

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.sort_elements(type='VIEW_ZAXIS', elements={'EDGE'})
```

python console prompt failed:
RuntimeError: Error: View not found, cannot sort by view axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you launch the script from a text editor, Blender don't know about what 3D view it should use, so you should define it.

Here is the example, script gets the biggest 3D view area from current workspace:

Then this area overrides context, which is always the first value in ops functions:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

def get_biggest_area(workspace, type):
    max_size = 0
    nextArea = None
    for screen in workspace.screens:
        for area in screen.areas:
            if area.type == type:
                size = area.width * area.height
                if size > max_size:
                    nextArea = area
                    max_size = size
    return nextArea

override = {'area': get_biggest_area(bpy.context.workspace, 'VIEW_3D')}

bpy.ops.mesh.sort_elements(override, type='VIEW_ZAXIS', elements={'EDGE'})
```

The example for the first area in the list, without size measuring:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

def getArea(type):
    for screen in bpy.context.workspace.screens:
        for area in screen.areas:
            if area.type == type:
                return area
            
override = {'area': getArea('VIEW_3D')}

bpy.ops.mesh.sort_elements(override, type='VIEW_ZAXIS', elements={'EDGE'})
```

Comment: Thanks, the code is perfect. I'm new to blender python for the time being and this question is costing me a lot of time. Thanks, you solved the problem。